# Windows command to search directory for a specific name, then move its files to parent

Tags: windows, cmd

I've been trying to get a command to work:

```
for /r /d %d in (*) do if /I "%~nxd"=="_Success" for /f %f in (%d\*) do if exist %f move %f ..
```

I'm intending the command to do the following:

1. Descend the directory tree and find directories that are named "_Success"
2. Move files (if they exist) to the parent directory.

I have been using `help` and the follow threads to get me started:

[How to move all files with specific extension from all subdirectories to their parent using CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357233/how-to-move-all-files-with-specific-extension-from-all-subdirectories-to-their-p)

[Batch Script to Find a Folder inside Sub Folders and get Folder Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724449/batch-script-to-find-a-folder-inside-sub-folders-and-get-folder-path)

However I'm getting a few errors back in my output:

```
C:\migration_files\vault>if /I "document" == "_Success" for /F %f in (C:\migration_files\vault\document\*) do if exist %f move %f ..
...
C:\migration_files\vault>if /I "_Success" == "_Success" for /F %f in (C:\migration_files\vault\faqs\_Success\*) do if exist %f move %f ..
The system cannot find the file C:\migration_files\vault\faqs\_Success\*.
C:\migration_files\vault>if /I "_Success" == "_Success" for /F %f in (C:\migration_files\vault\patch\_Success\*) do if exist %f move %f ..
The system cannot find the file C:\migration_files\vault\patch\_Success\*.
```

EDIT -
It seems to mostly working except that the file is being moved to the working directory.

Comment: I would recommend PowerShell rather than cmd.exe shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mihai_mandis with his solution at this link:

[batch moving file from subfolder to parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080795/batch-moving-file-from-subfolder-to-parent-folder)

I modified it slightly to the following:

```
@echo  off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r /d %%d in (*) do (
  if /I "%%~nxd"=="_Success" (
    for /f %%f in ("%%d\*") do (
      call :GETPARENTPARENT "%%f" ret
      echo ret=!ret!
      move /Y "%%f" "!ret!"
    )
  )
)

goto:EOF

:GETPARENTPARENT
set fileP=%1
echo received=%fileP%
for %%a in (%fileP%) do (
    set parent=%%~dpa
    cd !parent!\..
    set PPPath=!cd!
    for %%x in ("!PPPath!") do (
         set "%~2=%%~dpnx"
    )
)
GOTO:EOF
```